# How to use multiple description attribute on Enum

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

How we can define and use the multiple description attribute on an Enum?

```
public enum EnumWithDescription
{
    [CustomDescritption("job-view")]
    [Description("analyics-job-view")]
    JobView
}

class CustomDescritption: DescriptionAttribute
{
    private string extraInfo;
    public string ExtraInfo { get { return extraInfo; } set { extraInfo = value; } }

    public MyDescritptionAttribute(string description)
    {
        this.DescriptionValue = description;
        this.extraInfo = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

decorate attribute with AllowMultiple

```
[AttributeUsage(AllowMultiple = true)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute {}
```

More info: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.allowmultiple.aspx)